# Could not create connection to database (ColdFusion)

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I'm creating a simple CRUD application via ColdFusion. I'm going to ColdFusion Administrator Panel at `http://localhost:8600/CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm`, and adding a "New Data Source". But I get the following error:

```
Connection verification failed for data source: dsnMyVariable
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up. 
The root cause was that: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
```

[![DSN SQLNonTransientConnectionException Error][1]][1]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting Coldfusion 9 with MySql 5 on Ubuntu 9.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257081/connecting-coldfusion-9-with-mysql-5-on-ubuntu-9-10)

Comment: What settings did you use for the DSN (Database, Server, Port, Username, ...). Is the database on the same server as CF?

Comment: I use standard settings (MySQL server, localhost, 3306, root).
Same IP addresses, but different ports. CF on the http://localhost:8600 and DB on the http://localhost:3306.

Comment: Did you set  up a user to connect to MySQL? Are the permissions correct? And is your CF DSN setup to look for MySQL on Port 3306? Using the correct JDBC string?

Comment: No, I didn't set up a user, I use already existing 'root', I suppose 'root' has permissions for my problem. My CF DSN setup to look for MySQL on Port 3306. Where I can to find jdbc string?

Comment: Are you able to connect to your database with MySql Workbench with the same username, password and port?

Comment: It's okay for testing, but normally you'd create a separate user, instead of using "root". Anyway, 1) can you log into mysql from the command line? `mysql -u root -p`? 2) Is port 3306 open? You can check using something like `telnet 127.0.0.1 3306`.

Comment: Yes, Twillen, I'm able to connect to my database with MySql Workbench and that set of params which I try to use in CF Administrator.  <br/>  Ageax, Yes, I can log into mysql from comman line. I wrote `mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1` then I entered the password and I successfully connected. When I wrote "telnet 127.0.0.1 3306" I saw: `J 8.0.11&Giw2><r h[;E{"n*'caching_sha2_password` and 10 seconds later `Connection to host lost`. What is means? Is port open or not?

Comment: @RomanKharitonov - It's open. Otherwise, you'd have gotten a connection failed message like `Could not open connection to the host, on port 3306...`.  Hmm... when you say *I use standard settings (MySQL server, localhost....)*  I'm not sure the values entered are correct.  One cause of the NonTransient... error is an incorrect "Server" name, like setting it to "SomeInvalidName" instead of "localhost". It should be set to: `Database: YourDatabaseName | Server: 127.0.0.1  | Port: 3306 | UserName: root  | Password: (YourPassword)`.

Answer (score 10):

**Update:**

After installing MySQL 8, I got the exact same error message when creating a DSN. It seems to be a compatibility issue with MySQL 8. Checking the [System Support Matrix for ColdFusion 2016](https://helpx.adobe.com/pdf/coldfusion2016-support-matrix.pdf) only shows MySQL 5.7, so MySQL 8 probably isn't supported or compatible with the built in drivers.

Installing a [newer JDBC driver](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) seemed to fix the problem and allow the DSN to verify.

1. Stop the ColdFusion 2016 Windows Service
2. Download the latest JDBC driver from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/. Currently, the latest version is v8.0.11.
3. Unzip and copy the new driver jar (`mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar`) into directory `{cf2016_root}\wwwroot\WEB-INF\lib`
4. Find the *old* MySQL driver jar and rename it so it doesn't have a `.jar` extension. Example, rename `mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar` to `mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar.old`. (The actual location and version number may vary, but it's usually located in `{cf2016_root}\lib\`)
5. Restart the ColdFusion 2016 Windows Service

Finally, create a new DSN using *Driver Type = Other* and enter the following. Just replace "YourDatasourceName" and "YourDatabaseName" with the correct values.

- CF Data Source Name:  `YourDatasourceName`
- JDBC URL:
  `jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/YourDatabaseName?tinyInt1isBit=false&`
- Driver Class:  `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`
- Driver Name:   `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`
- User name:     `root`
- Password :    `(your  password)`

---

Without seeing your real DSN settings, this is just a guess, but... verify the *Server* setting is correct. Since MySQL is running on the same machine as CF, enter either `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`

[image: Server Name Localhost]

I confirmed that entering an **invalid** server name like *NotARealServerName* (no computer by that name on the network) produces the same error you're seeing when you try and verify the DSN in CF11.

[image: Invalid Server Name]

[image: Verify DSN SQLNonTransientConnectionException]

Once you get it working, I'd strongly recommend [creating a separate user account](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-users.html), granting the appropriate permissions, and using that with the CF DSN (instead of "root").

Answer (score 3):

Problem was with **version** [mysql connector java](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/).
First time I used the latest version `Connector/J 8.0.11` and need to use previous version `Connector/J 5.1.46`. Advice of Ageax's helped me a lot!
Work it both `MySQL 5` and `Other` drivers.
[image]

Comment: Glad you finally got things working =) Weird that v8.0.11 didn't work for you with MySQL 8. I didn't try 5.1.46, only 5.1.39 which didn't work MySQL8. The right driver makes all the difference! Just be aware the "MySQL5" label is misleading.  It's just a hard coded label, so CF'll uses whatever version of the driver it finds in the CF class path 5.x, 8.x, whatever ;-)

Comment: Yep, you're right. For anyone reading, I can confirm it works with 5.1.46 too. (On my install, it also works with 8.0.11 too, but use whichever of the two works for you).